# A Problem with Uniformly Cauchy and Uniform Convergence on Nested Intervals

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, uniform-convergence, cauchy-sequences

I was reading about convergence of Fourier series and a "demonstration technique" appears to me to be wrong. The idea is: Take $F_n \colon (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ as the n-th summand from the Fourier series of $f \colon (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$, and supose that: $$\forall \delta>0, \epsilon>0, \exists N\in \mathbb{N} \colon m,n > N \implies|F_n(x)-F_m(x)|<\epsilon, \forall x \in (\delta,1).$$
ie, $(F_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is Uniformly Cauchy in, so it must be Uniformly Convergent (on $(\delta,1)$), and taking the limit of $\delta \to 0$, one can conclude that $F_n \to f$ uniformly with domain $(0,1)$.

Here's why i don't think this is right: Let $f_n \colon (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function sequence with $|a|<\infty$ and supose that $(\delta_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a numerical sequence such that $a<\delta_j<b$, $\forall j \in \mathbb{N}$, and $\delta_j \to a$. Let's call $f_{n}^{j} = f_{n}|_{(\delta_j,b)}$ the restrinction of $f_n$ to $(\delta_j,b)$, then i propose the:

**Proposition:** $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is Uniformly Convergent if, and only if, for every $j \in \mathbb{N}$, the sequence $(f_{n}^{j})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is Uniformly Cauchy and, $\forall \epsilon>0$ the sequence $(N_j(\epsilon))_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded, where $N_j(\epsilon)$ is such that $|f_{n}^{j}(x)-f_{m}^{j}(x)|<\epsilon, \forall m,n > N_j(\epsilon)$ and $x \in (\delta_j,b)$.

If i didn't make any mistake, the proof is:

$(\Rightarrow)$ If $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is Uniformly Convergent, $\exists f \colon (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that, $$ \forall \epsilon>0, \exists N(\epsilon) \in \mathbb{N} \colon n>N(\epsilon) \implies |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon, \forall x \in (a,b). $$
Using the triangular inequality $|x+y|<|x|+|y|$, we have, $\forall m,n > N(\epsilon/2)$: $$ |f_n(x)-f_m(x)| \leq |f_n(x)-f(x)|+|f_m(x)-f(x)| < \epsilon, \forall x \in (a,b) $$
ie, $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is Uniformly Cauchy. The inequality above follows for $x \in (\delta_j,b) \subseteq (a,b)$, so we can take, $\forall j \in \mathbb{N}$, $N_j(\epsilon) = N(\epsilon)$, thus $(N_j(\epsilon))_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a bounded (constant) sequence.

$(\Leftarrow)$ If, for every $j \in \mathbb{N}$, the sequence $(f_{n}^{j})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is Uniformly Cauchy, we can take, $\forall \epsilon>0$, $N_j(\epsilon)$ such that $$n,m>N_j(\epsilon) \implies |f_{n}^{j}(x)-f_{m}^{j}(x)|<\epsilon, \forall x \in (\delta_j,b)$$
By hypotesis, $(N_j(\epsilon))_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded, so there's $N(\epsilon) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $N(\epsilon) \geq N_j(\epsilon)$, $\forall j \in \mathbb{N}$. Now, note that: $$\delta_j \to a \implies \forall x \in (a,b), \exists j \in \mathbb{N} \colon a<\delta_j<x<b \implies f_n(x) = f_{n}^{j}(x) $$
Then, $\forall x \in (a,b)$, $\exists j \in \mathbb{N}$, wich satifies: $$ n,m > N(\epsilon) \geq N_j(\epsilon) \implies |f_n(x)-f_m(x)| = |f_{n}^{j}(x)-f_{m}^{j}(x)| < \epsilon $$
ie: $n,m>N(\epsilon) \implies |f_n(x)-f_m(x)|<\epsilon, \forall x \in (a,b)$, and $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is Uniformly Cauchy.

The rest of the proof is, by no mean, original. Take, for every $x \in (a,b)$, the numerical sequence $(f_n(x))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, wich is Cauchy. By completness of $\mathbb{R}$, $\exists f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f_n(x) \to f(x)$, this define a function $f \colon (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$. Thus: $$ \forall \epsilon>0, \exists N(\epsilon) \in \mathbb{N} \colon n,m>N(\epsilon) \implies |f_n(x)-f_m(x)|<\epsilon$$
Taking the limit $m \to +\infty$ and by the punctual convergence $f_m(x) \to f(x)$, follows: $$|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon, \forall x \in (a,b)$$
ie, $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is Uniformly Convergent on $(a,b)$. $\square$

$$\dots$$

If this proposition is true, some examples (i mean, theorems) do not provide proofs of Uniform Convergence. For example:

**(Lema 3.1 - from: análise de fourier e equações diferenciais parciais / Djairo Guedes de Figueiredo. 4a. ed. 2000)** Let $\psi$ be a periodical function with period $2L$ defined by:

$$\psi(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix} -\frac{1}{2}(1+\frac{x}{L}) & -L \leq x < 0 \\ 0 & x=0 \\ \frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{x}{L}) & 0 < x \leq L \end{matrix}\right.$$ Then the Fourier series of $\psi$ converges uniformly to $\psi$ in any interval without points of the form $x=2Ln$, $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Here, the author used the Abel's lemma (for summation by parts) to find, to $\Psi|(\delta,L)$, the bound: $$ |\Psi_n(x)-\Psi_m(x)| < \frac{2}{m \cdot \sin\left(\frac{\delta L}{2\pi}\right)} $$
This is, taking $N_\delta(\epsilon) \geq 2/\left(\epsilon \cdot \sin\left(\frac{\delta L}{2\pi}\right)\right)$, one can proof the uniform convergence of $\Psi_n \to \psi$ on $(\delta,L)$. But: $$\delta \to 0 \implies \sin\left(\frac{\delta L}{2\pi}\right) \to 0 \implies N_\delta(\epsilon) \to +\infty,$$ so this argument cannot proof the uniform convergence on $(0,L)$.

**(Lema 1.2 - from: EDP: um curso de graduação / Valéria de Magalhães Iório. 4a ed. 2018)** The function defined by: $$ K(x,y,t) = \frac{2}{b}\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} K_k(x,y,t) = \frac{2}{b}\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{\sinh(k\pi x/b)}{k\pi a/b}\sin\left(\frac{k\pi t}{b}\right)\sin\left(\frac{k\pi y}{b}\right) $$
is such that $K(x,y,t) \in C^{\infty}([0,a) \times \mathbb{R}^2)$ and satify $K_{xx}+K_{yy}=0$.

Inside this lema, the author claims that $K_n \to K$ uniformly, arguing that, for $0 < \epsilon < a$ and $(x,y,t) \in [0,a-\epsilon) \times \mathbb{R}^2$: $$ \frac{b}{2}|K_k(x,t,y)| \leq \exp\left( -k\frac{\pi(a-x)}{b} \right) \leq \exp\left( -k\frac{\pi\epsilon}{b} \right) $$
Therefore you can apply Weierstrass M-test to get that, if $N(\epsilon)$ satifies,
$$ n > N(\epsilon) \implies \sum_{k=n}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{e^k} < \frac{\epsilon}{\exp\left( \frac{\pi\epsilon}{b} \right)} $$
then: $$ m,n > N(\epsilon) \implies |K_n(x,y,t)-K_m(x,y,t)| < \epsilon, \forall (x,y,t) \in [0,a-\epsilon) \times \mathbb{R}^2. $$
But again, $$\epsilon \to 0 \implies \frac{\epsilon}{\exp\left(\frac{\pi\epsilon}{b}\right)} \to \frac{0}{1} \implies N(\epsilon) \to \infty$$

$$\dots$$

I'm not into analysis, so it can be that i'm wrong with this proposition, but if you can take a time to judge it carefully, i'd appreciate the feedback of yours. Also, if you can leave references of alternative proofs for **Lema 3.1** and **Lema 1.2** above, it'll be usefull to me.